# How to do boolean slicing in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, boolean, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe. I would like to slice based on a comparison between the 2 columns. For instance in the following example I would like to extract rows where column `x` is larger than column `y`:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y':[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})

d[d[:"x"]>d[:"y"]]
```

By doing so I get an error:

> "unhashable type: 'slice'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need omit `:` and use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
d[d["x"]>d["y"]]
```

Sample (changed last value):

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y':[4, 5, 6, 7, 3]})
print (d)
   x  y
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  4  7
4  5  3

print (d["x"]>d["y"])
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

print (d[d["x"]>d["y"]])
   x  y
4  5  3
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer works in the above example but still not in another scenario:
Imagine  that I have a data frame with 2 columns A and B. They contain strings. I would like to extract those rows where string in A is contained in B. I use d[d["A"] in d["B"]] but I now get an error as follows: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: Thank you jezrael. The command d[d["x"].isin(d["y"])]) d0es not give me an error. Which is an improvement!!! :-) But still does not solve my problem. I have lines were column X is, say "abc" and column Y is "xxxabcxxx" bust the command above does not extract it. why?

Comment: Yes, so need `d = pd.DataFrame({'A':['abc','d','r t','rr','tt'], 'B':['xxxabcxxx','bb','d','tttrrtt','rrtt']})
print (d)` and then `print (d[d.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1)])`

Comment: YES MAN!!! It works!!!! But why the operator "in" does not work? What does 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed  " 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" mean?

Comment: Main problem is pandas use numpy arrays, so if need compare with `in` need apply.  Then `in` is used for comparecolumns A and B in each row - it have to compare scalars.